# Insert Array into MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have created a test that is all multiple choice.One of the questions is a has checkboxes.

```
<br><br><b><div><legend><p style="margin-right:20px"><font color="red">*</font>
15.) Select your favorite colors (select all that apply)</legend></b><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q15[]" id ="multi61" value="a" class="css-checkboxbox" ><label for="multi61" class="css-labelbox radGroup1"> Red </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="q15[]" id ="multi62" value="b" class="css-checkboxbox" ><label for="multi62" class="css-labelbox radGroup1"> Black </label><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="q15[]" id ="multi63" value="c" class="css-checkboxbox" ><label for="multi63" class="css-labelbox radGroup1"> Blue </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="q15[]" id ="multi64" value="d" class="css-checkboxbox" ><label for="multi64" class="css-labelbox radGroup1"> Green </label><br>
</p></div>
```

The problem that I'm having is that when you select multiple options, the values are added into an array. I want to add these values to one column. I know that I can't put a whole array into one column. There are two options:

1. To add each item into its own column
2. Put all values into one string

But I can't figure out how to do either.

Comment: The word you are looking for is "serialization".

Comment: You can insert to Mysql as json. use json_encode function

Comment: Just a little tip: finish your database design first, adjust the HTML later. You don't even consider it relevant enough for the question, so I suspect it isn't normalised.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowing user to select multiple answers, then it is fine with your string, goes into one column. This can be done in either two ways.

1. `Serialize` And `UnSerialize` array of multiple answers.
2. `JSON` encoding/decoding of array of multiple answers.